# i have to click submit link at least twice to work. why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, popup

I hava a login popup,when there is no session popup appears and then when i click submit link after write my user_id and password, nothing happened. but when i click second time everything works .i think it is about page loading but i have no idea to fix it. anyone any idea ? thanks

EDIT:  i realized something when i enter the wrong values (data.tip==='hata') it works in first time, but when i enter the right values i have to double click to work but i still cant handle it .

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
 ///////////////////////////////////General Popup
function launch() 
{
$('#sign_up').lightbox_me({centered: true, onLoad: function() { $('#sign_up').find('input:first').focus()}});
 }
            
$("#sign_up").lightbox_me({centered: true, preventScroll: true, onLoad: function() {
$("#sign_up").find("input:first").focus();
}});
    
$('table tr:nth-child(even)').addClass('stripe');
 /////////////////////////////////////////// PopUp End
$("#log_in").click(function(e)  // This is not working in first time 
{
   
var kullanici_adi=$("#kullanici_adi").val();
var sifre=$("#sifre").val();
   
  
$.ajax
({
type: "POST",
url: "girisislemi.php",
data: {kullanici_adi : kullanici_adi,sifre:sifre},
dataType:"json",
success: function(data) 
{ 
  if(data.tip==='yonetici'||data.tip==='kullanici')
  {
 $("#log_in").addClass("close");
 $ele.lightbox_me();
 $ele.trigger('close');
 }
 if(data.tip==='hata')
 {
  $('input[type=text]').css( "border", "3px solid red" );
  $('input[type=password]').css( "border", "3px solid red" );
 } 
    }
   });   
   
   e.preventDefault();
   });
   
            
        });
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
    
</head>

<body>
               
            <div id="sign_up">
                <h3 id="see_id" class="" >Can I see some ID?</h3>
                <span>Please sign in using the form below</span>
                <div id="sign_up_form">
                    <label><strong>Username:</strong> <input type="text" id="kullanici_adi" class=""/></label>
                    <label><strong>Password:</strong> <input type="password" id="sifre"  class=""      /></label>
                    <div id="actions">
                        <a class="form_button " id="log_in" href="#">Sign in</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    
    

 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I try your code in JSFiddle and I have an error: $ele variable is not defined so I add the definition in the success callback and if your returned json has the good tip property, it's working the first time on my side.

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
    ///////////////////////////////////General Popup
    function launch() {
        $('#sign_up').lightbox_me({centered: true, onLoad: function() { $('#sign_up').find('input:first').focus()}});
    }

    $("#sign_up").lightbox_me({centered: true, preventScroll: true, onLoad: function() {
        $("#sign_up").find("input:first").focus();
    }});

    $('table tr:nth-child(even)').addClass('stripe');

    /////////////////////////////////////////// PopUp End
    $("#log_in").click(function(e) { // This is not working in first time
        var kullanici_adi=$("#kullanici_adi").val();
        var sifre=$("#sifre").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "girisislemi.php",
            data: {kullanici_adi: kullanici_adi, sifre: sifre},
            dataType:"json",
            success: function(data) { 
                // --- Some log to verify the content of data.tip
                console.log(data.tip);
                if(data.tip==='yonetici'||data.tip==='kullanici') {
                    $("#log_in").addClass("close");

                    // --- Here I define the $ele variable to use it after.
                    $ele = $('#sign_up');
                    $ele.lightbox_me();
                    $ele.trigger('close');
                }
                if(data.tip==='hata') {
                    $('input[type=text]').css( "border", "3px solid red" );
                    $('input[type=password]').css( "border", "3px solid red" );
                }   
            }
        });         

        e.preventDefault();
    });


});
```

Comment: So I edit the answer. It's work for me with just a little modification.

Comment: thank you but it still the same  and i realized something when i enter the wrong values (data.tip==='hata') it works in first time, but when i enter the right values ı have to double click .